# Calculating light temperature

Tags: lighting

I'm currently building a ceiling light fixture as a test to see if I can create a diy-product to rival the IKEA Trådfri and Philips Hue ceiling lights. The current plan is

- A cheapish fluorescent ceiling fixture. I can get these for about $15 a piece. I'll just rip out all the electronics.
- Arilux AL-LC01 or similar. An RGB led-strip controller taking 5V-28V input and giving 12V out with upto 4A per channel (3 channels).
- Two or three led strips of different color temperature. Probably trying with two for the prototype.

I'm going to reprogram the controller so ignore it's RGB-output, I'm going to use it as a generic 3-channel LED-strip controller.

My question, in all of this text, is: Is there any way I can calculate the resulting color temperature?

If I have a warm strip and a cold strip (about 3000K and 6000K resp), is there any way to calculate the resulting temperature if I run one at 40% brightess and the other at 80%. What I'm looking for is ideally a formula that lets me define my wanted color temperature and brightness, and I'll get a percentage for each strip in return.

(Assume that the strips/leds are so close that they mix perfectly)

Comment: First off you’re assuming the color temp of the strip you purchase is accurate and is what it says it is, I’m not sure this is accurate with the current flood of cheap strips from China.  I purchased “warm white” “3000k” on amazon.  While it’s a pleasing white light light everyone I’ve had the conversation with thinks it’s closer to 4100k “cool white” than it is to incandescent (around 2700k usually).   (Yes I provided controlled samples of 2700k, 3500k and 4100k to compare). While the led strip clearly had more yellow it also had too much blue to be called 3000k.

Comment: This is true. But if you go for the slightly more expensive ones you get a fairly accurate rating and a CRI of 90+. About $26 for 5m-strip with 60led/m. And the question is not hardware dependent... Given two light sources of two different temperatures, can I calculate a resulting temperature based on the brightness of the two sources assuming a perfect blend.

Comment: It’s calculable, but keep in mind 3500k (for example) is already a mixture of wave lengths at different levels, thus one manufacturers 3500k may have a slightly different “recipe” than anothers.  Google “spectral power distribution”.  Also a hard to find source of learning is GE and Phillips lamp catalogs from 20+ years ago— they always had a spectral graph showing intensity at each wavelength. I find it hard to find those today, occasionally on a retail package but mostly forgotten of late.

Comment: Do you understand what "all the electronics" you'll "just rip out" do?

Comment: Yes, and I don't want any of it. I just want a fixture that's metal backed, looks ... alright (what can you expect at $15), and mounts to the ceiling. I'm not going to use the fluorescent tubes, so I don't need the ballast or the driver. I'm going to stick the strips to the metal using the tape that's on the back. If I could buy fixtures without the electronics, I would.

Answer (score 1):

The National Electrical Code requires light fixtures to be listed. Meaning tested by a listing agency such as Underwriters Laboratories.

That aside if this is for your own personal use, the total lumens of the light strips should be known. If they are the same and both strips are on 100% it would seem your color temperature would be an average of the two. That's the simple answer.

However, different colors of light have different energy levels and may be perceived as brighter than others. Such as, blue luminescence may appear brighter than red. A thorough study of RGB color theory would be appropriate.

Or, you could just get some lights and experiment with them. That's probably easier.

Good luck!

Comment: It's just for personal challenge, and I'm not in the US anyway ;) And I have thought a bit about it and found that if I want to have a set upper brightness, I can never have both strips at 100%. I want the brightness to appear mostly the same on the whole temperature spectrum, so I'll need some kind of crossfade algorithm. I found one for audio which says that 100% of both channels is about 70% on each, but I'm not sure if an algo for audio is directly translateable to light.

Comment: Sounds like a fascinating experiment. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not easily or reliably, no. The issue is that LED's output is not a continuous spectrum: they emit bands of discrete colors. The average frequency of those bands determines color temp. The uniformity and count of the bands determines CRI. While you know the average of the bands on each strip, you don't know the factors. Bands might overlap, or they might be slightly apart, and those two things "mix" very differently.

If you had a spectrograph and a reference for human eye's sensitivity at each frequency, you *could* calculate the light temperature, exactly, even aside from manufacturing effects, trans-florescence, cross-fluorescence, different current responses, source interaction, and spec headroom. But you can't often do that from a datasheet or typical product copy.

That being said, you will get *somewhere* between the two, and your endpoints are known, it's just the *exact* distribution between the two that is difficult to predict. You might not care what the numbers are, so long as they play well, which they should.

Comment: I know it's doable, maybe not to a specific degree of K, but both IKEA and Philips have their "ambience" bulbs that do this exact thing.

Comment: yes, for a given set of known LEDs, you can calibrate the LED drive ratios to actual color temps using a light meter. they make the light, so they can spec the two, measure them, then calibrate the app. You can probably do something like that once you have the lights, with some work, you just can't do it precisely from specs alone. unless the specs are really detailed.